# The Consistency of Arithmetic

Tags: reference-request, logic

I believe that within ZFC (or maybe even a weaker subset of ZFC) there is a proof of $\mathbb{N}=(\omega,+,.,<,0,1)\models{PA}$. What would be a standard reference for this?

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the definition of ordinals, their order and arithmetic, and the definition by recursion.

Comment: OK. Thank you. That was a lot more simple than I thought it would be.

Comment: What does PA stand for? I do not mean as abbreviation because I know that it is Peano Arithmetics. I mean what it stands for mathematically? Is it set of PA axioms or all sentences that are true and are deducible from PA in some system?

Comment: They usually stand for the axioms of Peano Arithmetic. Any model of PA also models all of the consequences of PA, and the set of consequences of PA has as a subset of it, all of PA. So for all intents and purposes there is no point in differentiating between the two concepts. Authors of books will usually implicitly identify the two concepts together.

Comment: However, note that if $\mathfrak{A}\models{PA}$ and $\mathfrak{B}\models{PA}$, then it is not necessarily true that $\text{Th}(\mathfrak{A})=\text{Th}(\mathfrak{B})$ (Since the consequences of PA is not complete. This result follows from Godel's incompleteness theorem).

Comment: @Asaf: Perhaps not so immediate. One has to develop the entire satisfaction relation, which means working with codes for formulas of PA.

Comment: @Carl: You're right of course. However I was taught about the satisfaction relation long before I was properly educated in the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, so it seems more like a simple obstacle to overcome, rather a tedious work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difficulty here is that there is a difference between showing

> For each axiom $\Phi$ of PA, ZFC proves $\mathbb{N} \vDash \Phi$.

and showing

> ZFC proves $\mathbb{N} \vDash \text{PA}$.

The difference is that in the former case the quantifier over formulas is in the metatheory, while in the latter case the quantifier over formulas is in the object theory (which is ZFC in this case).

To prove the second statement, the key point is that ZFC proves the following

> For each coded formula $\phi(n)$ in the language of PA, with one free variable, the set $\{m\in \omega: \mathbb{N} \vDash \phi(m) \}$ exists.

This in turn relies on the fact that ZFC is able to construct the satisfaction relation for $\mathbb{N}$. Once you have these things, and you know that ZFC proves $\omega$ is well founded, it is straightforward to verify in ZFC that each instance of the (infinite) induction scheme of PA holds in $\mathbb{N}$.  It is also straightforward to verify in ZFC that $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies each of the finite number of remaining axioms (which make up $\text{PA}^{-}$)

So the main source of difficulty is just with formalizing into ZFC the fact that the single second-order induction axiom
$$
(\forall X \subseteq \mathbb{N})( 0 \in X \land (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})[n \in X \to n+1 \in X] \to (\forall n \in\mathbb{N})[n \in X]).
$$
implies every instance of the first-order induction scheme.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.